# How to add a button just after the first line in a paragraph of text

Tags: html, css

I want to have a paragraph where first line will have different font to appear as a title. Just after that text when first line ends I want to have a button to expand the whole message.

I am title **BUTTON**
This is detailed message which has more width than the first line. I hope you see what I am trying to achieve.

```
<p>
    I am title.
    This is detailed message which has more width than the first line. I hope you see what I am trying to achieve.
</p>

p::first-line::after {
  content: "BOTTON"
}
```

Comment: waht about u post some code?

Comment: Based on th title of the question, you can use ::first-line selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstline.asp

Comment: I have few answers on mind, but without more details, I'm not sure which one is better suited for you....

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. You will need javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D Are you suggesting to find the actual width by painting on a canvas?

Comment: No, you'll need to detect where the line breaks with javascript and insert the button there.

Comment: `:first-line` is a pseudo-element and cannot have it's own pseudo-element..at least not yet.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D but I don't want to handle the wrapping myself. I want to use wrapping of the browser as per the width available.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you are out of luck. As I said, this is not possible with CSS. I'd suggest you re-think your implementation. You're going to need JS anyway to expand the message.

Answer (score -1):

Please submit some code. This is all a bit unclear.

But I think you need this:

```
p::first-line { 
     --your css--
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<h1 style="display:inline-block">I am title</h1>    <button  style="display:inline-block"  onclick="showDetails()">Button</button>
<p id="details" style="display:none">this is details which has more width that the first line</p>
<script>

   function showDetails(){
      document.getElementById("details").style.display = "block";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe... He/she said "paragraph", not "heading" and there are some inline styling but question wasn't clear enough and I find answer good as question and maybe close enough to give him/her idea what to do so I don't think it deserves negative vote...

Comment: Thank you yeah i think after posting i realised that it may not be the correct answer.. i would have put in a comment but i do not have th "50" reputation points needed... so answer away i guess hahahah